# How do i structure data in javascript (using redux) which will consume lesser memory as well as easily modifiable in future if the logic changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, react-redux, javascript-objects

```
current: [
  { key: "Electricity", budget: { total: null, used: [] }, isAdded: false },
  { key: "Food", budget: { total: null, used: [] }, isAdded: false },
  { key: "Gas", budget: { total: null, used: [] }, isAdded: false },
  { key: "Miscellaneous", budget: { total: null, used: [] }, isAdded: false },
  { key: "Others", budget: { total: null, used: [] }, isAdded: false }
];
```

Under `budget > used` there will be an array of objects which will be interrelated to its parent object for example **Electricity**, and I would change the values of any of the objects under `budget > used` then `budget > total` will also reflect the changes.

Please advise if I should separate the two logic of parent and child.
And this is my first question here so please pardon me for any mistakes, comment if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you using 'current' array for. If your main concern is budget, maybe you can structure your data like this:

`budget: [{key, used[], total, isAdded}]`

One of the main concerns of maintaining states in redux is keeping the state as flat as possible. In your data structure there's an array of object where budget is another object nested in, which is a bad design, whereas there's only an array of object in my structure

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I have created another object under budget, it would be much easier to read the code when fetching and updating the nested key values. Can you tell me why it would be inappropriate to going with nesting to just one level ?

Comment: In your reducers, you can't mutate state. When you have lots of nesting it's difficult to change state without inadvertently modifying the state object because all JS objects are passed by reference. When you have a lot of nesting you have to make deep copies of the state object before modifying it.